# Our father's carpet is full of thumbtacks (sirandane)

Tags: riddle

Our father's carpet is full of thumbtacks.

**What is it?**

(*Source: my version of "tapis grandpapa plein punaises", a traditional "sirandane", french-creole type of riddle.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that

> In French the word used is *Grandpapa* or Grandfather...this might be morbid, but could the carpet be the sky and the tacks be the stars?

This is because

> *Grandpapa* might be walking on the sky in Heaven?

Comment: ya, this is the answer to the version I've heard.

Comment: yes! or r13("tenaq cncn" nf gjb jbeqf), but was worried that wouldn't come across in translation so I thought maybe r13("Bhe Sngure va urnira")

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> a field of grass?

Where

> the blades of grass resemble the pins on thumbtacks, pointing up

Comment: spiky grass, sure +1! but not the traditional answer